# Getting the \currentsection and \currentsubsection in memoir

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, memoir

As you know in `memoir` there's no easy way to get the current `section` and/or `subsection`, you can only get the `\currenttitle`, which tells you the header of the *last* sectioning command. That's a frustrating thing if you had issued `\subsection{...}` and you want to get the current `section` name.

This question arose from trying to generate List of Tables entries for `longtable`s with `\addcontentsline` using the current section/subsection name without showing a caption:

```
\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{\ignorespaces FMECA: \currentsection\ -- \currentsubsection}}
```

Is there a not-so-difficult way to get them as `\currentsection` and `\currentsubsection`?

[MWE in the answer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\gdef\currentsection{??}
\gdef\currentsubsection{??}
\newcommand{\setcurrentdivisions}[2]{%
         \ifstrequal{#1}{section}{\xdef\currentsection{#2}\gdef\currentsubsection{??}}{}%
         \ifstrequal{#1}{subsection}{\xdef\currentsubsection{#2}}{}%
}
\apptocmd{\M@sect}{\setcurrentdivisions{#1}{#7}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
 \section{aaa}
 Name: \currentsection\\
 Subname: \currentsubsection
 \subsection{bbb}
 Name: \currentsection\\
 Subname: \currentsubsection
\end{document}
```

Note that this solution still has some issues with [accented letters and `\addcontentsline`] and command in section headers: I've tried with several combinations of `\noexpand`, `\protect` and `\expandafter` but I've failed to get robust commands, so any improvement will be appreciated.

It should also be completed with handling of `\chapter` and `\part` reset of the `section` counter.

Comment: Within clearing the subsection-level title, you could use `\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname current#1\endcsname{#2}`.

Comment: Yes I've thought to write that but then trying to clear `\currentsubsection` drove me crazy ;-)